# How can I analyse this circuit to get a function for Vs in terms of Vin?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, electronic-load

I´m trying to build an electronic DC load using a circuit similar to this one. I saw this circuit in an application note saying that it uses the opamp as a differential amplifier. I´m trying to get Vs (V at sense resistor) in terms of Vin (Load waveform) of this circuit using superposition. The issue is that I want to define two different ground potentials, one for the signal circuit and the other one for the power circuit and I don´t really know how to handle it.

[image: Electronic DC Load]

I found the circuit in an article called ["How to Design an Optimal
Electronic Load for High Current, Low-Voltage Power
Supplies (Part 1)"](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/power/whitepaper/21126111/how-to-design-an-optimal-electronic-load-for-highcurrent-lowvoltage-power-supplies-part-1)

Comment: agustin jose - Hi, (a) Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules. (b) [This site rule](/help/referencing) requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see the site rule about printed material). Thanks for including the name of the article from which you copied the schematic. However for online material, a *link* to the source webpage is required. I found & added the link this time, but that's your responsibility :)

Comment: agustin jose For your application: (a) what is the maximum Vout, and (b) what is the maximum load current?

Answer (score 1):

> I saw this circuit in an application note saying that it uses the opamp as a differential amplifier.

The reason for choosing a differential amplifier is to allow the potential at SGND to be different than at GND. If \$V_{GND}\$ is considered 0V, then the common mode voltage, \$V_{CM}\$, can be arbitrary. The common mode gain of an ideal differential amplifier is zero.

> I´m trying to get Vs (V at sense resistor) in terms of Vin (Load waveform) of this circuit using superposition.

1. Vin is not the load waveform. It is the input voltage that controls the load waveform. The text would be better placed below the amplifier.
2. The symbol, \$V_S\$ is usually used for an source voltage. It is actually the output voltage of the buffered op-amp as well as the voltage across the sense resistor. So \$V_{sns}\$ or \$V_o\$ are better choices. \$V_o\$ will be used to to indicate the output voltage.

The diagram shows how to configure the circuit for analysis by superposition.

The input \$V_{i1}\$ sees a non-inverting amplifier. while, \$V_{i2}\$ sees an inverting amplifier. Using the standard formulas for the op-amp configurations and superposition it is easily determined that:

The differential gain \$\frac{V_o}{V_{in}}=\frac{1}{2}\$, and,
The common mode gain \$\frac{V_o}{V_{CM}}=0\$

where \$V_{in}=V_{i1}-V_{i2}\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIHQ3Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "Load waveform" refers to the output current due to the voltage \$V_{in}\$. The image refers to a gain of 100A/V. Use this to calculate the value of \$R_{sense}\$

> The issue is that I want to define two different ground potentials, one for the signal circuit and the other one for the power circuit.

You don't have to "define" a ground potential for the input voltage. It is generally unknown. That's the advantage of a differential amplifier.

If the common mode voltage is known, it must not be allowed to exceed the common mode voltage limit of the op-amp. In this case the \$V_{CM}\$ is reduced by a factor of 3 by the voltage divider \$\frac{R}{2R+R}\$. So \$V_{CM}\$ (defined or otherwise) must be less than 3 times the common mode voltage range indicated in the op-amp's datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

If all the voltage at all nodes in the circuit stay within acceptable bounds, say, +12V and 0V, then you could have one power supply to feed both the power circuit (that supplied current to the load) and the control circuit (the one that powers the op-amp).  All you need do then is provide a "load waveform" voltage that is correctly referenced to the opamp - this may require an "analog level shifter" which could be as simple as a current mirror with resistor load, refer link below:-

https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics-lab-voltage-level-shifter

However, if that is not the case (ie: the main power is, say, 200V which is far in excess of what the op-amp circuit can deal with) then you will need a more sophisticated means of control that includes a "floating power supply" for the op-amp circuit - one that can continue to supply the opamp with, say, +12V, as the output across the load increases from 0V up to, say, 200V.

Comment: Fabio Barone - Hi, Clarification questions to an OP should be asked as comments to the OP (usually in the comments immediately below the question, see [here](/help/privileges/comment) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)); not as questions within an "answer" (since then it isn't just an *answer* any more). I moved your questions into a comment in the right place. If/when the OP replies to your questions, then of course you can update your answer, if you want to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit, with some annotations to help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhBNST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming R1 = R3 and R2 = R4, then the relationship between output \$I_{OUT}\$, and inputs \$V_{IN1}\$ and \$V_{IN2}\$ is:

$$ I_{OUT} = \frac{R_2}{R_1R_S}(V_{IN1} - V_{IN2}) $$

Even though the potentials of the two inputs IN1 and IN2 are able to vary independently of GND, the permitted range is still constrained. While I haven't done any proper analysis, initially I would say that given op-amp supplies of \$V_{S-}\$ and \$V_{S+}\$, neither input IN1 nor IN2 can fall outside the range \$3V_{S-}\cdots 3V_{S+}\$. If for example, the negative op-amp supply is 0V, then you must ensure that both inputs remain above 0V, requiring that SGND be positive with respect to GND, or at least equal.

It's unusual to see the control inputs in such a system required to be isolated from the load itself, since the system producing those control signals *and* the load MOSFET and sense resistor are lumped together in the same box, and the only requirement is that *their own* power supply be galvanically isolated from the system being "loaded":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3LkY2.png)</sup>

If you insist on using control signals which are independent of the active load's ground, and you can't guarantee that they will never wander to some potential that will violate the \$3V_{S-}\cdots 3V_{S+}\$ range (or whatever the system's input constraints are), then you need some means of bringing signal potentials to within those limits, while still maintaining isolation.

There are a few ways to achieve that, which vary in complexity. You could use an isolation amplifier, like the [ISO124](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso124.pdf), which will keep you in the analogue domain. Or you might use digital PWM to operate an opto-isolator LED, and then filter the signal on the opto-isolator's output side to produce a steady(ish) DC control potential for the op-amp. You could go completely digital, and use microcontrollers and a DAC, with the two microcontrollers communicating over an opto-isolated I<sup>2</sup>C bus.

It seems to me that you likely will not need any of that, but without further information about your own application, it's impossible to guide you. I'll end here, until you tell us more about your project.